# "Typical" temperature of resistor at its rated power

Tags: power-dissipation

Many components (resistor, transistor, diode...) have their power ratings. One of the simplest example is a resistor: 0805 SMD usually rated at 125mW, 1206 as 250... However this should depend on many "external" conditions such as ambient temperature, forced air cooling, even topology (especially for SMD components).

In my opinion (correct me if needed) the main reason why manufacturers specifies power ratings of their components is to keep them at reasonable **temperature**. If so, can we say that the resistor should be heated to so-and-so degrees at rated power in some circumstances (just for example: at 25C ambient, no forced air cooling, open frame...)? Can I suppose that this temperature should be below human pain threshold (something around 60C?)?

I'd like to discuss this in general and not to involve some special cases like heat-proof components.

Comment: You're right. But unlike semiconductors, resistors don't need an awful lot of thermal maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

You can get some idea of the expected maximum temperature if the manufacturer specifies the temperature at which allowable dissipation drops to zero.

For example, from a [Yageo datasheet](http://www.yageo.com/documents/recent/PYu-RC_Group_51_RoHS_L_04.pdf) (two different models):

[image]

As you can see, either temperature is quite sufficient to sear human flesh. Usually its better to not operate such components near the limits of their allowable range. At temperatures much about 100°C life can be affected and it can result in PCBs and nearby parts deteriorating at an undesirably accelerated rate.

(If it isn't obvious, you would expect the temperature of the MRA632 to be 155°C at maximum power and 70°C ambient, and at (say) 40°C ambient to be more like 125°C).

Comment: If I get you thought right I should really avid to use components at their rated power :)

Comment: @RomanMatveev: Well yes, that's basic engineering.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I was aware of this but the info above shows that I should keep components at 20-30% of the rated power (or I should calculate thermal condition very carefully or do real-life tests)

Comment: @RomanMatveev - Different resistors will have different curves, but if you derate by 30%, in general you don't need to do careful analysis. The exception is if the resistor is somehow thermally insulated from its surroundings, such as being enclosed an a small box, on a pcb which dissipates a lot of power.

Comment: This graph just shows how the max power degrades as the ambient temperature goes up. How can you deduce the resistor temperature at 50% power from this?

Answer (score 2):

> In my opinion (correct me if needed) the main reason why manufacturers specifies power ratings of their components is to keep them at reasonable temperature.

Yes, but the question is "*Why* should a component be kept at a reasonable temperature?" The short answer is *product reliability*. For example, when a component operates "hot" its operational/service life tends to decrease; the component tends to fail sooner. Hot components can also detrimentally affect everything around them: the printed circuit board could suffer "blister" delaminations, pad delamination, etc.; heat from the hot component is radiated into nearby components, possibly changing how those components operate, and so on.

> If so, can we say that the resistor **should be heated** to so-and-so degrees at rated power in some circumstances (just for example: at 25C ambient, no forced air cooling, open frame...)? [Emphasis added]

I would say "No." When selecting components for use in circuits, specific properties are deliberately *derated* to help ensure the end product's reliability over time. For example, if a resistor in a circuit is expected to dissipate 1/4 Watt of power under normal operating conditions, the circuit designer might select a resistor that can dissipate 1/2 Watt to ensure the resistor does not operate "hot" under normal operating conditions. (Hint: search the Interwebs using the keywords "circuit component derating guidelines".)

> Can I suppose that this temperature should be below human pain threshold (something around 60C?)?

I'm unsure how to answer this question. There are various standards that define safety-related guidelines for specific product categories. For example, the temperature for scalding water is around 45°C. One would presumably avoid designing a circuit to be contained within a child's toy that would get anywhere near this hot under normal operating conditions (product liability, engineering ethics, and basic morality). In some other product, an operating temperature of 45°C might be perfectly reasonable.